# Encrypt Headers sent to Laravel?

Tags: laravel, http-headers, laravel-5

This code is from the Laravel, VerifyCsrfToken.php. It's comments explain a few things. I'm sending a request from Angular to Laravel via restangular. The token is being sent correctly (I think) but the decrypt an invalid data exception. I can make this code work by removing the Decrypt call at the end. I've looked and looked, found no reference to the header needing to be encrypted before sending, I wouldn't even know how to do that.

```
protected function tokensMatch($request)
{
    $token = $request->session()->token();
            //from log, $token = UD6zHpg6lQYa9Xdz69kmOa3D2BBr12ErbhJD744x

    $header = $request->header('X-XSRF-TOKEN');
            //from log, $header = UD6zHpg6lQYa9Xdz69kmOa3D2BBr12ErbhJD744x

    if ( StringUtils::equals($token, $header)) Log::info('Token' . $token . " -- Header " . $header);

    return StringUtils::equals($token, $request->input('_token')) ||
        ($header && StringUtils::equals($token, $this->encrypter->decrypt($header))); 
                        //original line - Decrypt Error - invalid data

                ($header && StringUtils::equals($token, $header));
                        //my alternative - works!

                        //HOW SHOULD THE HEADER BE ENCRYPTED when sent????
                        //MY Current HEADER...
                        //X-XSRF-TOKEN: UD6zHpg6lQYa9Xdz69kmOa3D2BBr12ErbhJD744x
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem I just used the Encrypter to encrypt before I used it in angular my token.

```
 $encrypter = app('Illuminate\Encryption\Encrypter');
    $token = $encrypter->encrypt(csrf_token());
```

Alex